# how to stretch the first element in a row of elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.eltops {
   display: flex;
   background: #eee;
   color: white;
 }

 .elmark {
   background: blue;
 }

 .sbtn {
   background: green;
   border-right: 2px solid gold;
   padding: 0 9px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='eltops'>
   <div class='elmark'></div>
   <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
   <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class='eltops'>
   <div class='elmark'></div>
   <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
   <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
   <div class='sbtn'>C</div>
 </div>
```

.`eltops` is a row of elements

`.elmark` is always single. It is empty (without any text inside) and should be on the left side and stretched via all available space.

`.sbtn` are of various count (2-3-4-5) and should be on the right side

how to do this, using flex or grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to expand the blue div to full width, this is how you do it.

```css
.eltops {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  color: white;
}

.elmark {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.sbtn {
  background: green;
  border-right: 2px solid gold;
  padding: 0 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='eltops'>
  <div class='elmark'></div>
  <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
  <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='eltops'>
  <div class='elmark'></div>
  <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
  <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
  <div class='sbtn'>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Just make this change:

```
.elmark {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flex:1` or any value you see fit, this will make `.elmark` stretch for the size available.

```css
.eltops {
    display: flex;
    background: #eee;
    color: white;
}

.elmark {
    background: blue;
    flex: 1
}

.sbtn {
    background: green;
    border-right: 2px solid gold;
    padding: 0 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='eltops'>
    <div class='elmark'></div>
    <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
    <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='eltops'>
    <div class='elmark'></div>
    <div class='sbtn'>X</div>
    <div class='sbtn'>P</div>
    <div class='sbtn'>C</div>
</div>
```